# How to return data from RabbitMQ consume function in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rabbitmq

I have consume function like this.

In this case when i put console.log() in consume callback function, i see messages coming from queue.

**Function 1**

```
 async function consumeData() {
  try {
    const connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost:5672");
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue(queueName);
    let consumedData;

    channel.consume(queueName, (message) => {
      consumedData = message.content.toString();
      console.log(consumedData);
      channel.ack(message);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
  }
}
```

But i dont wanna log this data. I wanna return and use it like this.

**Function 2**

```
 async function consumeData() {
  try {
    const connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost:5672");
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue(queueName);
    let consumedData;

    channel.consume(queueName, (message) => {
      consumedData = message.content.toString();
      console.log(consumedData);
      channel.ack(message);
    });
    
    return consumedData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
  }
}
```

When i run function 2 i cant return any data. How can i return data from this consume function?

Answer (score 0):

return it after trycatch

```
 async function consumeData() {
  var consumedData = {};
  try {
    const connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost:5672");
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue(queueName);
    let consumedData;

    channel.consume(queueName, (message) => {
      consumedData = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());
      channel.ack(message);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
  }
  return consumedData;
}
```

and call the function using `await`

```
const data = await consumeData();
```